# Reading bash environment variable set using parameter substitution into Python variable

Tags: python, bash, environment-variables, substitution, dotenv

I have the following environment variables in my `.env` file:

```
DT="2019-01-01"
X=${DT//-/}
```

The variable `X` has been set using Bash's parameter replacement, using the `${parameter//pattern/string}` format to replace all occurrences (Documentation [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)).

Now, to read the environment variables into Python, I have created a Python class `Config` in a file `config.py`:

```
from dotenv import find_dotenv, load_dotenv
import os

class Config:
    def __init__(self):
        load_dotenv(find_dotenv())

        self.X = os.environ.get('X')
```

In a `python` shell, I run:

```
In [1]: from config import Config

In [2]: c = Config()

In [3]: c.X
Out[3]: ''
```

Here `c.X` is an empty string `''`, where as I want it to be `'20190101'`.

How do I load the correct value of the environment variable into a python variable?

Edit: When I type `echo $X` in a bash script, it prints the correct value. For example, a bash script `sample.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
source .env

echo $X
```

When run, I get:

```sh
$ sh sample.sh
20190101
```

Comment: I don't see you referencing `DT` anywhere.

Comment: also try `$ env` in your bash first to make sure `X` is set to what you want.

Comment: Have edited the question for clarifications @hiroprotagonist

Comment: how do you start python then? you may have to `export X` in bash...

Comment: @hiroprotagonist, I added the export, it works the way I need it to now, thanks! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added an `export` in my `.env` file in this way:

```
DT="2019-01-01"
export X=${DT//-/}
```

This allowed me to get the correct value of `c.X` in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Dotenv does not use Bash; it parses the file internally. See the [dotenv GitHub page](https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv).

Directly use `DT` instead:

```
self.X = os.environ.get('DT').replace('-', '')
```

Comment: I need to use the variable X without hyphens as a part of another variable name later on in my `.env` file as well. It would be better if I could resolve this in the `.env` file itself rather than in Python.